# ViewModel-to-ViewModel communication

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I'm working on a area of an application that consists of the following parts:

- Explorer - Contains a TreeView
- PropertyInspector - Contains a PropertyGrid
- Editor - Contains an Explorer and a PropertyInspector

As you can see, the parts are organized in a hierarchical fashion. My question is:
How do I make the selected item in the tree view used by the explorer the selected object of the property grid used by the property inspector?

When the tree view raises the SelectedItemChanged event a command is sent to ExplorerViewModel. The PropertyGrids SelectedObject is bound to a property on the PropertyInspectorViewModel. How do I connect the two view models? One approach could be to let EditorViewModel attach a method on the PropertyInspectorViewModel to an event raised by the ExplorerViewModel when the command is received but is this the way to go or can it be solved through data binding somehow?

The reason why the editor doesn't use a tree view and property grid directly is because the explorer and the property inspector, together with all the undo/redo functionality, validation code etc, are meant to be reused in other areas.

Comment: search for RelayCommand implementation ,
than at one vm the publisher you execute the command , and in the subscriber implement it .    
i'll later post a real implementation . FYI your bushiness logic is of no interest try phrasing the question technically

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a MVVM framework. I had similar requirements and decided to adopt [Tony Sneed's Simple MVVM Toolkit](http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/). It is very lightweight,very well documented and easy to understand, provides very useful capabilities and basically does must of the MVVM plumbing for you.

What you need in this case is make use of the Message Bus features:

"**MessageBus**

*Sometimes you need to pass messages among view-models in your application.  A good example would be when you want to navigate to a particular view based on some business logic.  It would not be a good idea to reference the main view-model directly from another view-model.  Doing so would create interdependencies between view-models that would be difficult to maintain (a phenomenon referred to as spaghetti code).  This is where a message bus (also called an event mediator or aggregator) comes in handy. The CustomerViewModel, for example, can then send a message to the message bus using a specific token, and the MainPageViewModel can subscribe to receive a message whenever someone sends a message with this same token to the message bus.  Message tokens are simply strings that can be defined as constants in a class.*" [From the Programming Reference page](http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Programming%20Reference)

In addition to that I also used [Josh Smith's `RelayCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) to simplify `ICommand` notifications as @eran otzap suggested

Answer (score 0):

The editor VM should coordinate the two child VMs.

Add a selected item property to explorer VM (if it's not there already) and make sure it fires property change notification.

The property inspector VM should have a similar property that is the item to show properties of.

The editor then watches the explorer VM's selected item property for changes, and when it changes passes the new item to the property inspector VM.

There's no need to involve a message bus here. Message buses are for ViewModels that are loosely coupled to pass messages to each other. For example application wide notification that a file has been opened.

If you used a message bus here then any reuse of the VMs would also trigger the message, which is not what you want.